# What are the origins of the чу/щу rule?

Tags: орфография

Whenever I see a quotation from the medieval chronicles (or even later sources like the time of Tsar Alexey), ч is followed by ю every single time. When and how did the rule change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthography of Russian recension of Church Slavonic uses *у* and *а* instead of *ю* and *я* after sibilants.

This rule had been mechanically copied into Russian orthography by early Russian grammarians like Lomonosov:

> В окончаниях единственного первого лица глаголы с предыдущею согласною имеют всегда *у*, а *ю* принимают токмо согласные *л, н* и *р*: *молю, храню, орю*. Итак, неправильно пишут: *хочю, лѣчю* вместо *хочу* и *лѣчу*.

and Vostokov:

> Гласные *я, ю* после *ц, ж, ч, ш, щ* сами заменяются гласными *а, у*… Таким образом производится *вижу* вместо *вижю*.

So this rule, as well as preserving the *ъ* at the end of words and making the letter *ё* a variant of *е*, not *о*, is only to make Russian orthography to be more consistent with that of Church Slavonic.

Comment: It is 100% definite that in Old Church Slavonic the sounds denoted with the letters _s, ц, ч, ж, ш, щ_ were always **palatalized**.

Comment: @YellowSky: you're right, brain fault on my end.